# Win Forms User Control Doubling all margins, heights, widths etc when dynamically added to a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls, flowlayoutpanel

I am dynamically adding multiple user controls to a flowlayoutpanel

when i run the form, the size of the user control has doubled to what it is on the designer.

This is the same for all measurement properties like margins, heights, widths of all controls within the user control.

As for the scale i've seen no warning and other panels/user controls are working correctly in other forms, does this rule out that issue as i'm unsure on how to change DPI-unaware. My user control width is set to exact same width as the FLP width (which works fine on other forms)

User control in designer - [image]

User control displayed in form - [image]

Its happened before, I can't find anything online but when i deleted and re-added the FLP I had some success. However I have tried recreating the FLP and custom UC and it is still the same. Please help

using vb.net framework  4.7.2

Comment: Is your application DpiAwares? Is (are) the test screen(s) scaled? Are you designing with a scale other than 100% (i.e., you have seen and ignored the banner that VS shows at the top when you're not designing at 100% scale)?  -- Clarify *when i run the form, the size of the user control has doubled to what it is on the designer*: aren't you adding the UCs at run-time? Do you mean that the resulting size is larger than the container FLP? So the UCs *overflow*? Or that you set a specific size to your UCs that, it appears, is not respected when the layout is performed? Other?

Comment: As for the scale i've seen no warning and other panels/user controls are working correctly in other forms, does this rule out that issue as i'm unsure on how to change DPI-unaware.

My user control width is set to exact same width as the FLP width (which works fine on other forms)

User control in designer - https://gyazo.com/c0663b74b8953a66da23c57ef7576c2f

User control displayed in panel - https://gyazo.com/b118b17bc78c7d5b4cb77b319f00085b

Comment: All updated now

Comment: A FlowLayoutPanel looks like the wrong tool to use.  That looks like you should be using a TableLayoutPanel instead.

Comment: You are showing just one uc added to the flp. Why not use a panel? How are you adding it? It wouldn't hurt to show some code

Comment: Its not how they are being added that's the issue as they are working on other forms, something is wrong with the designer or some form properties. SHall i drop the whole designer form in lol?

Comment: The images, as they are, do not clarify the layout, mostly because the bounds of the FlowLayoutPanel are not visible -- You still haven't said what is the scale of your screen and whether you're designing at 100% scale. Anyway, study what in here: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms) and then see the answers here: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75978794/7444103) -- Use `app.config` to set a `PerMonitoV2` DpiAwaness

Comment: Also, to note, that if the scale mode the UC is `Font`, the Font is inherited from the Parent and its Parent container has a larger Font, then the UC will scale accordingly when its layout is performed

Comment: Yep, that's fixed it. The UserControl AutoScaleMode was set to 'Font'. Changing it to none has fixed it all, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the AutoScaleMode property on the user control from Font to None fixes this issue